# How to get row count in groovy sql

Tags: groovy

Am new to groovy. Want to know how to get the number of rows from  a given sql result returned form an sql query below. I have googled lot but didn't find the proper solution.

Here is my sql query class code

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource);

    try
    {
        data = sql.rows("select field_value,form_table_column_name from 
               form_tbl where form_id=1");
        sql_one.close()

    } catch(Exception e) {

       System.out.println(e)      
    }
```

Comment: data.size() should give you the count of records returned.

Comment: Thanks:) Worked. Netbeans didn't give me an autosuggestion 'size'

Comment: Not a problem. Added it as an answer (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the count or size of the records returned used `data.size()`.

Answer (score 24):

Here is the code to get the count of rows in grails. Firstly autowire the datasource in your service and create an Sql object from that as shown.This Sql should be imported from groovy.sql.Sql

```
Sql sql = new Sql(datasource)
```

Then with the code below u can get the count as long.

```
def result = sql.firstRow('select count(*) as cont from <table>')
long count = result.cont
```

There is no need to fetch complete records from the database

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. data.size() in previous answer is just the size of array, but for a bigger dataset you will be using pagination and data.size() will return only page size and not the matching record count. Also if your purpose is only to get count then data.size() will be even worse as it will get all the records from database.

Comment: @saurabh If you look at the question asked, it was how to get a count of records returned from that specific query. Which is not using pages, and the stated purpose isn't just to get a count of records in the database. Which is why using .size() is still the correct answer to the question asked. I agree, if paging was being used, and if you only wanted the count .size() would not be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

`sql.firstRow()` is good to execute single-row SQL statements. Elvis operator helps if SQL result has no rows.

```
def cnt = SQL
     .firstRow('SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM form_tbl WHERE form_id=:id', id:1)
     ?.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind data.size() will still return 1, when using count(*) even if it returns 0, but the row count still=1

Answer (score -3):

```
sql.each row(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.table WHERE field= myField"){
    def total += it.count
}
```